# Passing ViewModel List Data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel as such:

```
public class AddNewsModel
{
    public List<CategoriesModel> Category { get; set; }

    public NewsModel NewsModel { get; set; }
}
```

where Category contains:

```
public class CategoriesModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and NewsModel contains:

```
public class NewsModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public String Headline { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public DateTime Publish_Date { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string TimeAgo { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a View where I take form input for News using NewsModel, but I want to display possible categories as a dropdown list or select Tag from the CategoriesModel.

This is My View:

```
<h2>Add a News Article</h2>
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <p class="alert alert-success" id="successMessage">@TempData["Success"]</p>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNews", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal" id="addNews">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("News ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(Model.Category), "Select Category")
            @*<div class="col-md-2">
                    <select form="addNews" id="NewsModel_Category" name="NewsModel.Category">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Category)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>*@
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Headline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.Headline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Headline, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Source, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.Source, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Source, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Publish Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.Publish_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Publish_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewsModel.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Summary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewsModel.Summary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Summary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.ImageURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.ImageURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.ImageURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This line of code:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(Model.Category), "Select Category")

gets all the categories, but only displays them as the model I have imported int the view, viz. "MVCApplication.Models.AddNewsModel", instead of a category like "World" or "Tech"

This code that I have commented, returns null when i try to get the data in my HTTPPost controller action using formcollection. I have tried using the ID that i have provided as: **string x= formCollection["category"];**

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
                        <select form="addNews" id="category" name="category">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.Category)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

How can I show the categories in my View, as well as get the value in the controller? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I am populating The Categories list in my controller action as:

```
public ActionResult AddNews()
    {
        AddNewsModel AddNewsModel = new AddNewsModel();
        AddNewsModel.Categories = new NewsArticles().GetCategories();
        return View(AddNewsModel);
    }
```

Changing my model to an Ienumerable instead of list causes errors in my controller I cannot seem to solve.

Comment: `new SelectList(Model.Category, "Id", "Name")` (but your view model should contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList`, not `List<CategoriesModel>`). And you cannot use the same name for the property you are binding to and the SelectList. It needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewsModel.Category, ...)`

Comment: I tried this as well as the answer by @Irakli
After explicitly casting in my controller action, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model should be like this:

```
public class AddNewsModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId {get; set;}

    public NewsModel NewsModel { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategorySelectList, "Select Category")
```

for more details -> [link](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: If I'm populating the Categories in my controller,
what changes do I have to make in the following code?
`public ActionResult AddNews()
        {
            AddNewsModel AddNewsModel = new AddNewsModel();
            AddNewsModel.Categories = new NewsArticles().GetCategories();
            return View(AddNewsModel);
        }`

Comment: AddNewsModel.CategorySelectList = new NewsArticles().GetCategories().Select(x=> new SelectListItem(){ Text= x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString(); })     i think it should work

Answer (score -1):

You should have both Cateogory and List with all categories in the model

```
public class AddNewsModel
{
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set;}
    public NewsModel NewsModel { get; set; }
}
```

View

update your dropdownlist with list.

```
<h2>Add a News Article</h2>
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <p class="alert alert-success" id="successMessage">@TempData["Success"]</p>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNews", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal" id="addNews">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("News ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, Model.Categories, "Select Category")
            @*<div class="col-md-2">
                    <select form="addNews" id="NewsModel_Category" name="NewsModel.Category">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Category)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>*@
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Headline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.Headline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Headline, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Source, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.Source, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Source, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Publish Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.Publish_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Publish_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewsModel.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.Summary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewsModel.Summary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.Summary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsModel.ImageURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsModel.ImageURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsModel.ImageURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: ' @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories, "Select Category")'

throws errors in the View saying that "Using the generic Ienumerable requires 1 type arguments",
"'SelectListItem' is a type which is invalid in the given context",
" The name categories does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Your code does not even compile! And if it did it would throw an exception.

Comment: Downvoters.. pls leave comment. it helps to improve the answer!!